# Where can I find all files that are checked out or locked for editing in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: central-administration, administration

I'm simply trying to add a web part to a page for some test development, but I get an error dialog saying, "The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user."

Is there somewhere in the SharePoint 2010 administration where I can see all checked out files (and who has it checked out)  and force check-ins?

All I can find with Google are code examples for listing the checked out files, but I feel like this should be available somewhere for admins...

Comment: Although it's not ideal you can enable publishing features to get the reports availability, one of the reports will show you this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Listing all checked out files](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/listing-all-checked-out-files)